# Click link to refresh page and send POST data?

Tags: php, post, hyperlink

I am building a PHP website that has one page that contains all of the UI (header, footer, etc.), and other pages that just contain the content. In my main file, between the header and footer, I put the code:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST["content"];
?>
```

I was planning to also provide the user with a hyperlink that would refresh the page while sending POST data, in this case the contents of one of the other php content files. How would I create this link?

Thank you very much,

Cello Guy

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Do mean post some data via a form to the same route?

Comment: @DavidJones I mean something along the lines of `<a href="`... and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use JavaScript to send the form, here is an example with jQuery:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="content" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($content) ?>">
</form>
<a href="#" id="myLink">Send</a>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#myLink').click(function(){
            $('#myForm').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't actually have a form. I'm just sending one field of POST, `content`, and that is already saved in the variable `$content` to send.

Comment: @CelloGuy In this case you should still use the form, but add the field you need to send into a hidden field. I've modified the source code to reflect this change.